# Netlify Error Page Not Found if I'm using windows.location.replace("url")

Tags: reactjs, netlify

In my ReactJS app I'm using `window.location.replace("/dashboard")` to redirect when user logs in and locally it's working fine but on Netlify after log in I get Page Not Found error Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site. Any suggestions please...

Comment: To solve this issue create _redirect file in to react public folder with  this content /* /index.html 200

Comment: If you have an answer, use the Your Answer box and enter your answer there, preferably after having read [answer] and following the advice there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the full path.

Such as:

```
window.location.replace('https://address.com./dashboard');
```

Comment: I just found solution. To solve this issue i created _redirect file in to react public folder with  this content /* /index.html 200

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue create **_redirect** file in to react **public folder** with this content

> /* /index.html 200

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we have just one html file (index.html) in our react application and all that routing and navigation is done in this file

So to solve this problem you need to create in your application folder a file with this name: (netlify.toml) and write this lines of code into :

[[redirects]]

from = "/*"

to = "/index.html"

status = 200